# Add event listener to element after DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

I have some trouble with adding event listener to element after DOM updating.

I have some page, that sort two lists and save the stage.
I can move elements between this lists by d&d and by clicking special button. And it work fine for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/bmj32ma0/2/

But, I have to save stage of this lists, and after reloading I have to extract stage, so I write code below.

```
    function saveFriendsLists(e) {
    if(e.target.classList.contains("b--drugofilter--save-button")){
        var vkFriends = document.querySelector('.b--friends-from-vk .js--friends-container').innerHTML;
        var choosenFriends = document.querySelector('.b--friends-choosen .js--friends-container').innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem('vkFriends', vkFriends);
        localStorage.setItem('choosenFriends', choosenFriends);
    }
}

function loadFriensListFromStorage() {
    if(localStorage&&localStorage.choosenFriends&&localStorage.vkFriends){
        document.querySelector('.b--friends-from-vk .js--friends-container').innerHTML = localStorage.vkFriends;
        document.querySelector('.b--friends-choosen .js--friends-container').innerHTML = localStorage.choosenFriends;
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadFriensListFromStorage);
```

But after adding this, the preview functionality like D&D doesn't work. And I can't provide you valid jsfidle because, as I can understand, localStoradge reason or something.

When I tried to move my addEventListener to loadFriensListFromStorage function, like this:

```
function loadFriensListFromStorage() {
        if(localStorage&&localStorage.choosenFriends&&localStorage.vkFriends){
            document.querySelector('.b--friends-from-vk .js--friends-container').innerHTML = localStorage.vkFriends;
            document.querySelector('.b--friends-choosen .js--friends-container').innerHTML = localStorage.choosenFriends;
        }

    [].forEach.call(friends, function(friend) {
          friend.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    });
}
```

But that doesn't have any effect.

How can I fix this issue? Thx.

Comment: It's the variable *friends* defined in some place?

Comment: Yes, `var friends = document.querySelectorAll('.b--friend');`

Comment: I think you have to assign the variable again through a new querySelector after you change the dom.

Comment: When you load the list from storage you use `innerHTML`. Instead of moving the elements around you are replacing the lists children with new elements and therefore the elements stored in `friends` no longer exist. So like @MarioAlexandroSantini wrote, you will have to query for them again.